# Change quantity selector style in Wordpress with WooCommerce and Avada

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Where is the file where I can change the quantity selector's style? I want to change the border color to black and I can't find the file in which I need to do the changes.

Comment: Please provide more information on which themes/plugins you are using

Comment: I have the Avada theme and the plugin is Woocommerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [`Custom CSS`](https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/knowledgebase/how-to-make-custom-css-changes/) in the *Avada > Theme Options > Custom CSS* section.

The following snippet should do the trick:

```
.quantity, .quantity input {
    border-color: black !important;
}
```

The files that style the `.quantity` borders are in `Avada/assets/css/woocommerce.min.css` and `Avada/assets/css/style.min.css`, but it is recommended to use the [child theme](https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/special-features/avada-child-theme/)'s `style.css` or add [custom CSS](https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/knowledgebase/how-to-make-custom-css-changes/) via the Avada Settings.

---

**EDIT** at request of asker

You can also add other styles like rounded corners to the whole element as shown below:

```
.quantity {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: i tried with Theme Options and it workd perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you happen to know how can I add radius to them.. so the whole quantity selector would look like a pill button only with the outline border?

Comment: @MHerieta I have updated the answer to include rounded corners. Try increasing or decreasing the amount to meet your needs.